# How to subtract one variable from another when they are on different lines (based on different years) in R?

Tags: r, conditional-statements, difference

I am just wondering if it is possible for me to find the difference (in a new column within my data frame) by subtracting the fall value (19.0) in year 0 from the spring value (33.33) in year 1. I am hoping to generate a column with the difference.

Here is the data set:

```
   Group.1   spring   fall   year
1  2000-01-01 46.00000 19.0    0
2  2001-01-01 33.33333 19.0    1
3  2002-01-01 37.66667 19.0    2
4  2003-01-01 31.33333 13.0    3
5  2004-01-01 35.66667 13.0    4
```

Is there a way to do this that is not manually writing out each step?

I expect the first row of this new column to have an NA value.

I have tried a few different ways, but I cannot seem to get all of the conditions to work the way I want them to.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```r
library(dplyr)
dat <- tibble::tribble(
  ~"Group.1",   ~spring,   ~fall,   ~year,
"2000-01-01", 46.00000, 19.0,    0,
"2001-01-01", 33.33333, 19.0,    1,
"2002-01-01", 37.66667, 19.0,    2,
"2003-01-01", 31.33333, 13.0,    3,
"2004-01-01", 35.66667, 13.0,    4)

dat %>% 
  mutate(diff_fall = spring - lag(fall))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 5
#>   Group.1    spring  fall  year diff_fall
#>   <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 2000-01-01   46      19     0      NA  
#> 2 2001-01-01   33.3    19     1      14.3
#> 3 2002-01-01   37.7    19     2      18.7
#> 4 2003-01-01   31.3    13     3      12.3
#> 5 2004-01-01   35.7    13     4      22.7
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Unrelated question: did you use any specific addin to recreate their dataset based on their available version of the dataset in the question? if so, could you share which addin did you use?

Comment: Yes, that worked! Thank you! I just had to write " diff_fall = spring - lag(fall))"

Comment: @RuamPimentel I just did it manually in RStudio.  With column select, adding in a column of quotes or commas is really easy.  On the Mac, you can do it by holding down option and then dragging down on the trackpad to select a column.  Presumably it's alt instead of option on Windows.